# How to store lost used value in a variable and needs to use it when the application is started in android?

Tags: android

How can we store a variable value even the application is closed? And
needs to use that value when ever the application is opened.

The below shown is my code. From the below code I'll get cityname and
id of the city I need to use cityid in my next view. When ever I'm
closing the application I'm losing id and name of the city. So for this
I need to use last selected city as the default city for next time
when ever the application is opened.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    Button back;
    ListView lv;
    CitiesParser parsedDataSet;
    String url = "http://...........";
    String pos;
    String citypos;

    ArrayList<String> cid;
    MyArrayAdapter adapter;
    // SaxParsing xparsing;
    XMLParsing xparsing;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access" })
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        xparsing = new XMLParsing(url);

        ArrayList<String> cities = parsedDataSet.getdata();

        String[] scity = cities.toArray(new String[cities.size()]);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(SampleActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, scity);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        cid = parsedDataSet.getId();

        System.out
                .println("Hello from sample activity" + parsedDataSet.getId());

        System.out.println("before onclick in sampleactivity"
                + adapter.getItemId(0));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this,
                        "" + cid.get((int) adapter.getItemId(arg2)),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                citypos = cid.get((int) adapter.getItemId(arg2));

            }
        });

        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("cityid", citypos);

                System.out.println("Main PutInt" + b);

                Intent in = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, Home.class);
                in.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        /*
         * public static void storeToPreference(Activity c,String value) {
         * SharedPreferences myPrefs = c .getSharedPreferences("cityname",
         * Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
         * e.putString("yourkey", value); e.commit(); }
         */

    }

    private class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] items;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.citieslist, null);

            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
            tv.setText(items[position]);
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use shared preference we can store the in this, and we will get those values through out the application Using. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: have you got the answer?

Comment: put the function out side the class and it will remove your invalid error and according to your requirement you can change the function access modifier...

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SharedPreferences` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

This explains the different methods of data storage:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Call this method when you application is destroyed

```
public static void storeToPreference(Activity c) {
            SharedPreferences myPrefs = c
                    .getSharedPreferences(Util.USER_DETAILS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
            e.putString(Util.API_KEY, <value you wanted to put>);
            e.commit();
        }
```

Call this method on Start()

```
public static String getPreferenceValue(Context c) {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = c
                .getSharedPreferences(Util.USER_DETAILS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
         myPrefs.getString(Util.API_KEY, ""));
    }
```

Comment: what is Util.API_KEY in this line  e.putString(Util.API_KEY, <value you wanted to put>); is it name of the key can i give my own name here.

Comment: Util.API_KEY implies the Key which is string so you can give any proper Key name according to your project standards

Comment: Yes you can update the value whenever you want by calling the function  public static void storeToPreference(Activity c,String value) {
            SharedPreferences myPrefs = c
                    .getSharedPreferences(Util.USER_DETAILS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
            e.putString(Util.API_KEY, value);
            e.commit();
        }

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable storeToPreference i'm getting this error.

Comment: i have posted my code please once check it and provide a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function like this

```
public static void storeToPreference(Activity c,String value) {
            SharedPreferences myPrefs = c
                    .getSharedPreferences(Util.USER_DETAILS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
            e.putString("yourkey", value);
            e.commit();
        }
```